# When entering canvas url, facebook automatically redirect to oauth dialog not index page

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

When entering 'https://apps.facebook.com/seemyfuture', Facebook automatically redirect users to Oauth dialog, while i didn't write any script for that.

Users suppose to land on my index page on 'example.com/seemyfuture/index.php' first. On the index page, i allow user to read something out first then if they are ok they can click a link which will lead them to OAuth dialog.

Is this due to any setting or any facebook rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your app settings, and *disable* “authenticated referrals” in the auth dialog settings …